# "SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol" Exception while calling IBM Blockchain

Tags: python, ssl, ibm-cloud, hyperledger

I try to access the IBM Hyperledger Blockchain from python. Unfortunately I get an SSL Protocol error while trying to connect. I already searched the internet and specially stackoverflow to find a solution for it. Here is what I did:

1. Setup an IBM Hyperledger Blockchain service and get the URL to work with.
2. I tried the CURL call to access the API

`curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "https://SOMETHING_vp0.us.blockchain.ibm.com:443/network/peers"`

This works fine for me (wonder why I don't need a passwd but it works).

3. I tried to access the same API from python, but got an error. 
   Python2.7 => 2.7.12, requests => 2.10.0 on mac

   import requests

   url = "https://SOMETHING_vp0.us.blockchain.ibm.com:443/network/peers"

   response = requests.get(url)

   print response.status_code

Accessing https://www.google.com works without a problem, but blockchain returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ansi/development/hyperledger/mcp.py", line 9, in <module>
    response = requests.get(url)
  File "/Users/ansi/development/virtualenv/general/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 71, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ansi/development/virtualenv/general/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 57, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ansi/development/virtualenv/general/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/ansi/development/virtualenv/general/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 585, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ansi/development/virtualenv/general/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 477, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

What can I do to solve the problem?
Thanks a lot